# convert rte field to wyvern

Tags: richtext, wyvern

I have a live site with a Rich Text Editor field. The RTE field is really not allowing them to accomplish what I need them to be able to. specifically linking to files. So I have decided to use wyvern instead. In the past in EE2 I had changed fields from RTE or textarea to wygwam with no issue. In this case I have installed wyvern and created a test field just to make sure all was working well. When I go back to the main field to change the type from RTE to Wyvern wyvern is not listed as an option. In fact the options are very limited (email address, text input, textarea, URL)

Does anyone know why wyvern wouldn't be listed as an option or why the options are so limited? I really dont want to have to migrate all the data to a new field as I would have to copy paste everything and then go change the field name in all the templates.

Answer (score 1):

After much searching I found out this is not just Wyvern but an issue or design feature in EE3. Developers need to add what their fieldtype compatibility is but not all of them have. This post describes the same issue with wygwam. https://expressionengine.com/support/bugs/21302/field-type-not-changeable-after-creation You can follow the same instructions and change the fieldtype to wyvern.

As with anything backup your database first in case their are unintended consequences.